# Different xzing dependencies

Tags: android, zxing

I am working on an Android app that uses XZing to scan barcodes and have been reading a bunch of tutorials online, can see that two different dependencies are being used in different tutorials.

```
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
```

and

```
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
```

Can anyone tell me which one point to the official Xzing project and perhaps even, what the difference is?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: These two are two different libraries. Both uses `zxing` internally . You can use any of those . Follow the `README.MD`  from their repo.

Answer (score 0):

Official ZXing repository is on GitHub: https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Latest maven:

`com.google.zxing:core:3.3.2`

`com.google.zxing:android-integration:3.3.0`

You can always check on https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.zxing%22

Libraries you provide are just simplified implementation for ZXing.